# Styling the first letter of a particular word, etc

Tags: css

I'm trying to style a word with a big first letter and spacing for the other letters. My current solution is pretty ugly: see [here](http://www.dinkypage.com/117623) (and a malfunctioning jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HTnBP/)).

Ideally, instead of something ugly like this: `<dropcap>T</dropcap><span style="letter-spacing:.2em;">HERE</span><span style="margin-left:-.2em;"> is</span> nothing more unreasonable...`

I could have something sensible like this: `<dropcap>THERE</dropcap> is nothing more unreasonable...`

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Your jsFiddle is malfunctioning because you've wrapped your CSS in `<style>..</style>`, which is already done for you. It also wraps your code in `html` and `body`. This is more like it: http://jsfiddle.net/HTnBP/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use the [`:first-letter` pseudo-element.](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-firstletter)

> The `:first-letter` pseudo-element is
>   mainly used for creating common
>   typographical effects like drop caps.
>   This pseudo-element represents the
>   first character of the first formatted
>   line of text in a block-level element,
>   an inline block, a table caption, a
>   table cell, or a list item.

It's supported in IE8+ and all modern browsers.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/HTnBP/4/

---

For the other half of your question, try:

```
T<span>HERE</span>

div > span:first-child {
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    margin-right: -.2em
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HTnBP/5/

I don't really see the point in using a custom `dropcap` element. Unless you don't mind adding [extra complexity](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to support IE8 and lower, or you simply don't care about those browsers.

Comment: I've got so many spans and divs in my paragraphs that I'm a little worried about your method. Is there a way to do it as follows?: `<span class="dropcap">THERE</span>`. Thanks.

Comment: `:first-letter` will not work on an inline element such as a `span`, so with that HTML structure I suggest: http://jsfiddle.net/HTnBP/11/, or if you like your `dropcap` element: http://jsfiddle.net/HTnBP/12/

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. I wish I knew _why_ `:first-letter` won't work on inline elements, but knowing it certainly helps explain a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you can use this JS solution i found

http://webplatform.adobe.com/dropcap.js/